# NHibernate: Recursive queries

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I've got a basic tree structure that is stored in a single table.  Let's say this is my model:

```
public class TreeNode {
  public virtual Guid Id { get; private set; } 
  public virtual string Name { get; private set; }
  public virtual IEnumerable<TreeNode> Contents { get; private set; }
}
```

and the table:

```
TREE_NODES
  PK_NODE Guid
  FK_NODE_PARENT Guid
```

NODE_NAME Varchar

I want the following implementation where the return value is a TreeNode with the full eagerly loaded tree of its children and their children, etc.

```
public class Tree {
  ISessionFactory _sessions;
  public TreeNode GetBy(Guid id) {
    using(var s = _sessions.OpenSession())
      return s.Linq<TreeNode>().Single(n => n.Id == id);
  }
}
```

How would I do this mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you can optimize it - there is no recurtion in basic SQL. You can optimize it using server-side procedures (server specific - some servers, like MySQL does not support them) but it still be doubtful as you get non-recursive components.

Probably the best way is to walk down the tree in loading function and force the evaluation. Something like:

```
public class TreeNode {
  public virtual Guid Id { get; private set; } 
  public virtual string Name { get; private set; }
  public virtual IEnumerable<TreeNode> Contents { get; private set; }
}

public class Tree {
  ISessionFactory _sessions;
  public TreeNode GetBy(Guid id) {
    using(var s = _sessions.OpenSession()) {
      return LoadSubTree(s.Linq<TreeNode>().Single(n => n.Id == id));  
    }
  }
  private LoadSubTree(TreeNode node) {
    foreach(var n in node.Contents)
      LoadSubTree(n);
  }
}
```

PS. `Tree` is probably not the best place for `ISessionFactory`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "walk down the tree in loading function and force the evaluation"?  I don't know what that means.  What is a loading function in relation to nhibernate?

Comment: Yeah, this is just sample code.  Tree is more a stateless repository rather than an entity.  I found this article about hiearchies in NH: http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/05/14/how-to-map-a-tree-in-nhibernate.aspx

Comment: Here's another example for reference: http://refactoringaspnet.blogspot.com/2011/04/using-common-table-expressions-to.html